# Is it possible to change the font in a plugin tool window?

Tags: intellij-idea

I am trying to increase the font size for a plugin (Regex Tester Plugin) window.
I have tried changing the font under Appearance, also the Console font, in fact every font that shows up in the settings dialog. Every font in the system changes except the darn plugin!

I tried ctrl-scroll wheel (which is also enabled in the settings) but that just controls the editor window, not the plugin.

Is there any way (supported or hack) to get this font increased?

Comment: FYI IntelliJ IDEA includes this functionality out of the box. Just press Alt-Enter on a regular expression in the editor.

Comment: Well kind of. The regex tester does a lot more than just matches or not. It highlights the parts that match your selected group, supports flags, it's really much more. But thanks for the tip, that's a good one I was not aware of